# How is this working in c language. Output is 1 and 2 respectively. But how?

Tags: c, operators

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i = 1, j = 2, int n = (i < j);
    n = (i, j);
    printf("%d",n);
}
```

Question:So how is output coming here?

Comment: With the changed proper formatting you probably see that the code won't compile as you wanted a semicolon between `j=2` and `int n`.

Comment: What does *"Output is 1 and 2 respectively"* mean?

Comment: Please [edit] and show what output you get and what output you expect.

Comment: Does your code okay? I think there is a need for a semicolon before the declaration of n. like as `j = 2; int n = (i < j);`

Comment: I there a `printf` missing? That would account for the question title. When posting code here, pleaase copy/paste the *exact* code that you have.